# INSERT into ... SELECT doubles the number of rows in the target column, in MySql

Tags: mysql

api_log table has about 3 million rows.
api_log_temp is empty
Both are innodb and have the same structure.

When I run

```
INSERT into api_log_temp SELECT * FROM api_log
```

api_log_temp ends up with more than 6 million rows.

How can that be ?

Comment: do you have any triggers on api_log_temp?   perhaps you did this insert twice?

Comment: "do you have any triggers on api_log_temp?"

No

"perhaps you did this insert twice?"

No


I realized api_log_temp didn't have a primary key so I added one, truncated api_log_temp and tried again.
Surprisingly, it worked. But how the absence of a primary key caused rows to be re-inserted earlier is still a mistery to me.